# Contracting products of bilinear form

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

In the picture below ,I  don't know how to contract the $M_{\alpha\beta}$. I just used to the contract in Lee's book
$$
tr:T^{k+1}_{l+1}\rightarrow T^k_l \\
F\rightarrow trF(\omega^1...\omega^l,\cdot,V_1...V_k,\cdot)
$$
In fact, I am very strange with $\mathcal{P}(M_{\alpha\beta},h_{\alpha\beta})$.
Besides,  in the second red line why $N_{\alpha\beta}$ can be made so ?

Picture below is from the 212 page of [this](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]

Comment: Contract simply means multiply by the inverses of the object, so you have a polynomial in terms like M^ab × M_bc; the contraction simply means sum over repeated indices (in the above case, the repeated index is b).

Comment: To get such objects M^ab you multiply by the inverse of the metric ie h^ab, for example M^ab = M_ij × h^ia × h^jb